# How to implement verticall scrolling on mouse over in a <rich:datatable> in jsf+richfaces?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

Can any one help in  achiving this  requirement. Is there  any  attribute in  rich:datatable  has this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Extended  DataTable**](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/extendedDataTable.jsf?c=extendedDataTable&tab=usage)
Here is sample working code for the same

```
<div id="production-list-header-div">
  <rich:dataTable columns="3" columnsWidth="80,300" style="width: 100%;">
    <rich:column sortable="false">
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Projectnr." />
      </f:facet>
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column sortable="false">
      <f:facet name="header"> 
        <h:outputText value="Gidstitel" />
      </f:facet>
     </rich:column>
     <rich:column sortable="false"> 
       <f:facet name="header">
      </f:facet>
     </rich:column>
  </rich:dataTable>
</div>
<div id="production-list-rows-div" style="background-image: url('../images/div-border-left.jpg'); background-repeat: repeat-y; height: 400px; overflow: scroll;">
  <rich:dataTable value="#{productionHandler.productions}" var="prod"
      columns="3" columnsWidth="80,300"
      style="border-top-width: 0px; width: 100%;">
    <rich:column sortable="false" >
      <h:outputText value="#{prod.code}" />
    </rich:column>
    <rich:column sortable="false"> 
      <h:outputText value="#{prod.broadcastTitle}" />
     </rich:column>
     <rich:column sortable="false"> 
     </rich:column>
  </rich:dataTable>
</div>
```